# Why NSWindow without styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask can not be keyWindow?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow

Problem:
I have one window mainWindow and another `childWindow` added to `mainWindow`.
childWindow is kind of `WindowExt` class. This class I define for catch method call `[NSWindow becomeKeyWindow]` that must be called after `[childWindow makeKeyWindow]`.
If I create childWindow and try to make it keyWindow on next way:

```
WindowExt *childWindow = [[WindowExt alloc] initWithContentRect:addedWindowRect
                           styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask
                             backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                               defer:NO];
[mainWindow addChildWindow:childWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
[childWindow makeKeyWindow];
```

method `[WindowExt becomeKeyWindow]` for `childWindow` is called - all fine, `childWindow`become keyWindow.

But if I create childWindow as

```
WindowExt *childWindow = [[WindowExt alloc] initWithContentRect:addedWindowRect
styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask 
backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
defer:NO];
[mainWindow addChildWindow:childWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
[childWindow makeKeyWindow];
```

without `NSTitledWindowMask`, `[WindowExt becomeKeyWindow]` for `childWindow` is never called - `childWindow` doesn't become keyWindow.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That’s a Cocoa design decision: [windows without title or resize bar cannot become key window by default](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/canBecomeKeyWindow).

If you want a titleless window to be able to become a key window, you need to create a subclass of `NSWindow` and override `-canBecomeKeyWindow` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Original

**Swift 5** implementation of @user557219's answer

```swift
class NSPanelModified: NSPanel {
    override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

usage ⤵︎

```swift
var panel = NSPanelModified()
print(panel.canBecomeKey) // true
```

---

#### Update: As  Extension

Idk why I didn't just make this my first answer. NSPanel can also just be modified itself using an extension ⤵︎

```swift
extension NSPanel {
    open override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

same usage, just no custom NSPanel ⤵︎

```swift
var panel = NSPanel()
print(panel.canBecomeKey) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the style mask to `NSBorderlessWindowMask` in order to make it borderless