# Cocoa/OSX - NSTextField not responding to click for text editing to begin when titlebar is hidden

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a NSTextField in my window (added with IB) with a hidden title bar but when I click on it when the app is running, it does not respond or place a cursor in its field. Is there anything I am doing wrong? it is setup in the most standard way possible, an editable textfield on a window.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe it's set to be readonly?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question with a critical point that this only occurs when I set the window to have a hidden titlebar in IB

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why NSWindow without styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask can not be keyWindow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946342/why-nswindow-without-stylemasknstitledwindowmask-can-not-be-keywindow)

Answer (score 11):

Create a custom class that inherits from NSWindow, and set it as the NSWindow Object in InterfaceBuilder. Then override the following methods:

```
//
// canBecomeKeyWindow
//
// Overrides the default to allow a borderless window to be the key window.
//
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}

//
// canBecomeMainWindow
//
// Overrides the default to allow a borderless window to be the main window.
//
- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: +1: I assumed there was something I was overlooking - I didn't imagine it could be so complicated as to require subclassing and overriding methods like this. (Not that that's complicated, so much as it's not easy to track down/debug.)

Comment: Only "canBecomeKeyWindow" is needed for NSTextField to response. The window does not have to be the main window.