# How to make an NSWindow appear in front of other apps?

Tags: objective-c

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I'm new to Objective-C.

I'm making a menu bar app (doesn't show in Dock, only in menu bar), and for some reason when I open a window, it appears at the very back, behind all the other apps. I thought `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` would be enough, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

So how do I make the window appear in front of other apps?

Comment: Can you show us your code? An example of what you have tried so far will help us answer your question.

Comment: @Dan I have a menu item sending `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` to the window in the MainMenu.xib file. I also read something about `setLevel:`, but I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to activate it as well.

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

If this doesn't work, is your window title-less or anything like that? If so, you need to follow [Cocoa/OSX - NSTextField not responding to click for text editing to begin when titlebar is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634588/cocoa-osx-nstextfield-not-responding-to-click-for-text-editing-to-begin-when-t/11470145#11470145)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! And if I can ask, what does the `nil` do in `makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil`?

Comment: That's the `sender` object. You are supposed to pass the object responsible for doing the thing. Could be useful if you override `makeKeyAndOrderFront` someday. But the default implementation doesn't use it. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578139/objective-c-what-is-a-id-sender