# NSPanel not becoming key window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSPanel, which I want to set as `keyWindow` so that it should post `NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` but, even on calling the `makeKeyWindow` method, the notification is not being posted. Below is my code, but I am not able to figure out what is wrong with it:

```
newPanel = [[NSPanel alloc]initWithContentRect:windowRect
                                         styleMask:NSUtilityWindowMask
                                           backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                             defer:FALSE];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self 
                                            selector:@selector(test:) 
                                                name:@"NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification" 
                                              object:newPanel];
    // Create a slider and add to the panel
    NSSlider *slider = [[NSSlider alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, windowRect.size.width, windowRect.size.height)];
    [[newPanel contentView]addSubview:slider];
    // Set window attributes
    [newPanel setHasShadow:TRUE];
    [newPanel setFloatingPanel:TRUE];
    [newPanel setReleasedWhenClosed:TRUE];
    [newPanel setHidesOnDeactivate:TRUE];
    [newPanel setBecomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded:NO];
    [newPanel makeKeyWindow];
    [newPanel makeFirstResponder:slider];
    [newPanel orderFront:sender];
```

Now when I call `[newPanel makeKeyWindow];` the NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification should be posted and `-(void)test:(NSNotification*)aNotification` should get called. But it isn't getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code into a new project, and it didn't even display the panel, does it for you?  I could make it work by making a property, thePanel (the compiler didn't like the name newPanel, not sure why) and changing all references of thePanel to self.thePanel.  Also I added NSTitledWindowMask to the style mask argument (styleMask:NSUtilityWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask) and either moved the makeKeyWindow command to after the orderFront command or replaced those two with makeKeyAndOrderFront:self.window.

Comment: Yes its displaying the panel just fine. Also the notifications are being posted after adding `NSTitledWindowMask`. But the panel is now displaying a title bar which is at all required in my case. Anyway we can remove the title bar and still get the notifications posted.

Comment: I guess I got my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946342/why-nswindow-without-stylemasknstitledwindowmask-can-not-be-keywindow