# How do I go about handling Cocoa Events in a fullscreen application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyevent, first-responder

I have been trying to create an app for Cocoa without a nib/xib (No, I don't want to use a nib/xib. I want to be in full control programatically) and I can't seem to be able to catch the Events such as keystrokes and mouse clicks. Here is the code I have so far:

**Main.m**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];

        [app setDelegate:appDelegate];
        [app activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
        [app run];
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**AppDelegate.h/m**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSWindow *window;
}

@end

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GLView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSRect bounds = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

    GLView *view = [[GLView alloc]initWithFrame:bounds];

    window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:bounds 
                               styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                               backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                               defer:NO];
    [window setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
    [window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [window setContentView:view];

    return self;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

@end
```

**GLView.h/m**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface GLView : NSView

@end

#import "GLView.h"

@implementation GLView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Drawing code here.
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyView
{
    return  YES;
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString*   const   character   =   [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers];
    unichar     const   code        =   [character characterAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Key Down: %hu", code);

    switch (code)
    {
        case 27:
        {
            EXIT_SUCCESS;
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{

}
@end
```

Nothing I have tried for it has worked. I thought that by setting the view as the first responder I would be able to get the events. So far... Not working. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Remember, NO NIB.

Thanks,
Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that your window can actually become key, by subclassing and returning `YES` from `canBecomeKeyWindow`, because [windows without title bars cannot become key by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946342/why-nswindow-without-stylemasknstitledwindowmask-can-not-be-keywindow).

Next, your build target needs to be an application. I would guess that you're starting from the Command-Line Tool template in Xcode. This is fine, but you need to produce an application bundle in order for your app to recieve key events. Create a new target in your project that will build a Cocoa Application. It needs to have an Info.plist file (from which you'll want to delete the "Main nib file base class" entry) and have a "Copy Bundle Resources" Build Phase.

I can't quite figure out what all the other differences are in the build process, but starting from your code, I got the window to accept key events with these two steps.

Comment: Thank you very much Josh! I wasn't aware that windows without title bars can't become key by default. I was actually creating a cocoa application by default but then i did as you said and I created my own class subclassing NSWindow and in the implementation section just added `
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
`
Now my log is showing every click perfectly. Thank you once again.