# Delphi tray icon (NSStatusItem) for OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I am trying to add NSStatusItem in a Delphi application for OSX.  Searched for sample code to help me with that but got stuck when defining an interface:

Here is the code:

```
// Source: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=108449

unit Unit2;

interface

uses Macapi.ObjectiveC, Macapi.CocoaTypes, Macapi.Foundation, Macapi.AppKit,
Macapi.Helpers, Macapi.ObjcRuntime, System.TypInfo, FMX.Platform, FMX.Platform.Mac;

type
TFMXTrayItem = class(TOCLocal)
private
NSStatItem : NSStatusItem;
public
constructor Create;
destructor Destroy; override;
function GetObjectiveCClass: PTypeInfo; override;
procedure call_mymethod; cdecl;
end;

implementation

constructor TFMXTrayItem.Create;
var
NSContMenu : NSMenu;
NSContItem : NSMenuItem;
NSStatBar : NSStatusBar;
NSImg : NSImage;
AppBundle : NSBundle;
NSpImg: Pointer;
Path: String;
begin
inherited Create;

NSStatBar := TNSStatusBar.Create;
NSStatBar := TNSStatusBar.Wrap(TNSStatusBar.OCClass.systemStatusBar);
NSStatItem:= NSStatBar.statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength);
NSStatItem.setTarget(GetObjectID);

// Create context menu
NSContMenu := TNSMenu.Create;
NSContMenu := TNSMenu.Wrap(NSContMenu.initWithTitle(StrToNSStr('The caption')));

NSContItem:=TNSMenuItem.Create;
NSContItem:=TNSMenuItem.Wrap(NSContItem.initWithTitle(StrToNSStr('1. menuitem'),sel_getUid(PAnsiChar('call_mymethod')),StrToNSStr('')));
NSContItem.setTarget(GetObjectID);
NSContMenu.addItem(NSContItem);
NSContItem.release;


// Add menu
NSStatItem.retain;
NSStatItem.setHighlightMode(true);
NSStatItem.setMenu(NSContMenu);
NSContMenu.release;

// Get path to dir
AppBundle := TNSBundle.Wrap(TNSBundle.OCClass.mainBundle);
Path:=AppBundle.bundlePath.UTF8String+'/Contents/yourimage16x16.png';
NSpImg := TNSImage.Alloc.initWithContentsOfFile(StrToNSStr(Path));
// Create Icon
NSImg := TNSImage.Create;
NSImg := TNSImage.Wrap(NSpImg);
NSStatItem.setImage(NSImg);
NSImg.release;
end;

destructor TFMXTrayItem.Destroy;
begin
NSStatItem.release;
inherited;
end;

function TFMXTrayItem.GetObjectiveCClass: PTypeInfo;
begin
Result :=TypeInfo(IFMXTrayItem);
end;

procedure TFMXTrayItem.call_properties;
begin
// your event code of the menu item
end;

end.
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to declare the IFMXTrayItem interface?

Comment: So, what is IFMXTrayItem?

Comment: Found a sample of deriving from a Cocoa class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26408689 I believe IFMXTrayItem is similar to the MyNSWindow interface defined in that sample but I am not sure what it would inherit from.

Comment: Is it possible the author meant TFMXTrayItem

Comment: That also went through my mind but most of the samples I find pass an interface when returning from GetObjectiveCClass . Here is another one: http://www.verydemo.com/demo_c134_i32581.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work like this:

```
type

IFMXTrayItem = interface(NSObject)
['{7d2e4b38-61d9-4cf4-b78b-5f7c4188e9c0}']
  procedure call_mymethod; cdecl;
end;
```

**later edit:**

Added a GUID to the interface after reading [this](http://www.nickhodges.com/page/why-you-should-be-using-interfaces-and-not-direct-references.aspx):

> *This GUID is used by the compiler to identify uniquely this interface.
>   Strictly speaking, you can use an interface without the GUID, but you
>   can’t get very far using them as much of the RTL and most frameworks
>   that take advantage of interfaces will require that they have a GUID.*

So that is a random GUID I generated but if you use this in your code you should generate your own GUID.