# Other window comes to front when bring window to front

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

In my app I have windows that display notifications. I instantiate the controller from a xib and I call `makeKeyAndOrderFront` to make the window visible. I also adjust its level to `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel` so that it appears in front of others.

The problem is, when I click this window to use it, the main window for my app comes to front. I also have other Windows my app opens, and I noticed that the same behavior happens to them.

According to Apple's documentation on NSWindow, bringing a window to the front should not change the order of any other Windows, thus my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946342/why-nswindow-without-stylemasknstitledwindowmask-can-not-be-keywindow/4948795#4948795). An important piece I failed to mention here is that the windows in my app that exhibited this issue were titlebar-less.

By default, when you have a titlebar-less window, Cocoa doesn't allow it to become the main window. I subclassed NSWindow and overrode `canBecomeMainWindow` to return YES at all times and this solved my problem.

This also explained why my windows were resizable but the resize handles never showed up on their own; only main windows get resize handles!

Answer (score 0):

*Alternatives*

Have you considered using `NSAlert` to display those notifications?

I don't know what you want to show to the user, but if it is only a notification, `NSUserNotification` is a nice way too. The user gets informed, but not interrupted from what he is doing.

Comment: The notification is a full-blown NSWindow with functionality of its own (not unlike getting a Skype or a FaceTime call); I don't let it take focus from what the user is currently doing.

Comment: I see, let me take a look at this tomorrow!